# i am trying to make my ipcamera stream over webrtc usingnodejs and kurento media server

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, webrtc, kurento-media-server

i am new at webrtc and rtsp, while trying to make a project on webrtc i came to a halt in my code and after weeks of online search adn usng chatgpt am still not able to resolve my problem. I want to stream my ipcamera to webrtc but the code is not working properly.am not above to start the stream.

the code is given below

```
const wrtc = require('wrtc');
const kurento = require('kurento-client');
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const node_ffmpeg_stream = require('node-ffmpeg-stream');

const mqttonline_connection = require('../../mqttconnection/online_mqtt_connection');
const clientonline = mqttonline_connection.returnconnection();
const topiconline = mqttonline_connection.topic;

const RTSP_URL = 'rtsp://admin:password@192.168.0.100:554/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1';

async function startStreaming() {
  try {
    // Create Kurento client and pipeline
    const kurentoClient = await kurento('ws://localhost:8888/kurento');
    const pipeline = await kurentoClient.create('MediaPipeline');

    // Create WebRTC endpoint
    const webRtcEndpoint = await pipeline.create('WebRtcEndpoint');
    webRtcEndpoint.setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth(10000000); // Set max bandwidth to 10 Mbps

    // Create RTSP source and connect it to the WebRTC endpoint
    const rtspEndpoint = await pipeline.create('RtspEndpoint', {uri: RTSP_URL});
    rtspEndpoint.connect(webRtcEndpoint);

    // Start streaming
    webRtcEndpoint.gatherCandidates();

    // Subscribe to ICE candidate events and send them via MQTT
    webRtcEndpoint.on('OnIceCandidate', event => {
      const candidate = kurento.getComplexType('IceCandidate')(event.candidate);

      clientonline.publish('sdp', JSON.stringify(candidate));
    });

    // Subscribe to ICE connection state events and log them
    webRtcEndpoint.on('IceConnectionStateChanged', event => {
      console.log(`ICE connection state changed to ${event.state}`);
    });

    // Generate SDP offer and send it via MQTT
    const sdpOffer = await webRtcEndpoint.generateOffer();
    clientonline.publish('sdp', JSON.stringify(sdpOffer));

    // Start the RTSP source
    rtspEndpoint.play();

    // Listen for incoming SDP answers via MQTT and set them on the WebRTC endpoint
    clientonline.subscribe('answer');
    clientonline.on('message', (topic, message) => {
      if (topic === 'answer') {
        const sdpAnswer = JSON.parse(message);
        webRtcEndpoint.processAnswer(sdpAnswer);
      }
    });

    // Listen for incoming ICE candidates via MQTT and add them to the WebRTC endpoint
    clientonline.subscribe('candidate');
    clientonline.on('message', (topic, message) => {
      if (topic === 'candidate') {
        const candidate = JSON.parse(message);
        webRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
      }
    });

    // Handle errors
    webRtcEndpoint.on('Error', error => {
      console.error('WebRTC endpoint error:', error);
    });
    rtspEndpoint.on('Error', error => {
      console.error('RTSP endpoint error:', error);
    });
    pipeline.on('Error', error => {
      console.error('Pipeline error:', error);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error starting streaming:', error);
  }
}

startStreaming();
```

am getting the error as

```
  Error starting streaming: SyntaxError: Unknown type '[object Object]'
    at getConstructor (/home/user/Desktop/ghome/node_modules/kurento-client/lib/MediaObjectCreator.js:55:17)
    at createConstructor (/home/user/Desktop/ghome/node_modules/kurento-client/lib/MediaObjectCreator.js:74:21)
    at createMediaObject (/home/user/Desktop/ghome/node_modules/kurento-client/lib/MediaObjectCreator.js:140:23)
    at MediaObjectCreator.create (/home/user/Desktop/ghome/node_modules/kurento-client/lib/MediaObjectCreator.js:263:12)
    at startStreaming (/home/user/Desktop/ghome/extra/webrtc/mqttwrtc.js:25:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: {
    params: 'rtsp://admin:password@192.168.0.100:554/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1',
    type: 'RtspEndpoint'
  }
}
```